# How does ASP.NET Core generate 500 status code when there is an unhandled exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

If we throw an unhandled exception in a middleware like

```
throw new System.Exception();
```

then the browser will show:

> This page isn't working, localhost is currently unable to handle request HTTP ERROR 500

But how does ASP.NET Core generate that http 500 status code when there is an unhandled exception? Can anyone point out the source code at https://source.dot.net/ and show which class has a "try catch" block that handle the exception and set response code to 500?

I am trying to locate the code at `GenericWebHostService` (https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/GenericHost/GenericWebHostService.cs,fd20321226ab7078)

but I couldn't find the relevant code that does the job

to people who ask to setup a break point debug into ASP.NET Core source, if you throw an excpetion in a middleware

```cs
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private RequestDelegate next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDelegate) =>
        next = requestDelegate;

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new System.Exception();  // <----it won't break in VS because the unhandled exception is swallowed by asp.net infrastructure
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

but this excpetion won't break the execution flow, that's why browser is showing 500 error code, so must be some component swallows this unhandled exception, and I want to know which component/class does that

Comment: Set a break point on your `throw` line, and then you can actually debug into ASP.NET Core source code to find out the answer yourself, using [VS Code](https://halfblood.pro/how-to-step-into-net-core-source-code-in-vs-code/) or Visual Studio for Windows.

Comment: @Lex Li create a custom middleware and throw an exception and you will see the break point won't work

Comment: Read what I said again please. VS and VS Code both require special configuration, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/debug-aspnetcore-source?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

For a simple sample from `dotnet new web` (I tested against .NET 7), you can change its code in `Program.cs` to

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
    // Log the request
    Console.WriteLine($"Received request: {context.Request.Method} {context.Request.Path}");

    // Call the next middleware
    await next.Invoke();
});

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

If you set a break point on `throw new` line and debug further, you should see the `try`-`catch` pair lies in `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl` class,

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Process an individual request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context); // => Your exception from the middleware is  caught here.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.UnhandledException(ex);
```

For your specific sample, the `try`-`catch` pair you are looking for might be at another place, but simple debugging should reveal where.

Comment: if you remove the try catch block (I didn't use try catch)and run the app again, browser will display 500 status code, and I didn't use DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware

Comment: According to this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/418105/iam-getting-status-500-in-my-asp-net-core-code  which says "Web server IIS swallowed the exception and returned the HTTP 500", since I don't use IIS and I  use kestrel , so could you show me the source code of kestrel that swallows the unhandled exception? https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core/Internal/KestrelServerImpl.cs

Comment: @user22155685 instead of ambiguously posting descriptions that nobody understands, share your complete source code so that I might debug for you. Like I said, in this answer I showed what you might get when debugging the default sample from `dotnet new web`.

Comment: I found how the status code get set, https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core/Internal/Http/HttpProtocol.cs,1049 and https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core/Internal/Http/HttpProtocol.cs,600

Comment: @user22155685 Then you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, go to `Debug` > `Windows` > `Exception Settings` >`Common Language Runtime Exceptions` and check `System.Exception`.

Or another easy way, go into the normal action and throw new exception, you could see the following window display and be sure check the first one option:
[image]